Is there a form of the Arabic script without ligatures?
This comes from someone interested in typography familiar with the Latin and Hebrew scripts but not much with the Arabic script.
The Latin script (written or typeset) has many forms, including baroque, Gothic, Antiqua, grotesque. Some of them are connected, and some disconnected. When I see the Arabic script, it is always connected. Does Arabic has a form (possibly niche) where the letters are disconnected?
I have several ideas of how such a disconnected Arabic script would arise, but I can't find any example of that. The ideas:

Typewriters stamp every letter regardless of others, so there seems no good way to connect letters.
Someone feeling avant-garde tried to simplify the script, and it did not catch on.

The second idea is a parallel with how sans-serif fonts arose in modernist art as simpler forms, and they were at first niche, but they later became mainstream especially with computer screens.
I imagine that such a script would be similar to the Hebrew script because the Hebrew script is similar but usually disconnected.

Arabic typewriters did exist https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/international-journal-of-middle-east-studies/article/case-of-multiple-identities-uncanny-histories-of-the-arabic-typewriter/F5D9E8A8474FF2E32AB9063EC830FD18

Indeed, but the letters are still connected, as is shown in Figure 2.

Yep, that was my point: they invented a typewriter with connected letters so that was not a reason for a disconnected writing.

I found this article about disconnected Arabic typefaces: Quarantining on Disconnected Arabic Fonts: Kameel Hawa’s new take at the art of shaping Arabic letters
It is mainly about the typefaces Iklil and Tawtam. The letters there have two forms: nonfinal and final.
It mentions also Kameel's typeface Tashkeel, about which I couldn't find anything, and Nasri Khattár's Unified Arabic developed since the 1940s. These typefaces have only one form of every letter.
Also an interview about Unified Arabic which I found

I found also this forum thread with other examples, but it is mostly off-topic and has too much text, so I will not read it all: https://chez-ouam.foroactivo.com/t791-brief-history-of-the-traditional-arabic-type
